# Sorting Data Based On the Last column

Tags: vba, sorting, excel

So I have 6 columns (Columns A:F). Column A consist of dates while in between that B-E containing data based off of the dates. Column F contains the categories where it's either (L, RI, or R). I've already sorted all of the L's, RI's and R's together so I only want to sort within their own category.

My problem is that the dates are scattered within each category and I need to sort them by the oldest-newest date. So say for instance, the L's go down from F2:F18. So I need to sort the date from A1:F18 and only that part or else it'll mix in with the other data in category's RI, R. And the RI's go from F19:F24 so I would need to sort the data from A19:F24

I need a VBA code that sorts the dates from oldest-newest within their own categories. The data changes so sometimes there can be more or less categories.

I tried recording a macro to get a headstart but I literally don't know what to change because I'm new to VBA.  It would definitely make it easier if I don't have to manually select it. **Sorry if i'm not descriptive enough, I feel as though that I am pretty bad at explaining things but tried my best** Here is the code below:

```
Range("A1:F23").Select
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet4").Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet4").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A2:A23") _
    , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet4").Sort
    .SetRange Range("A1:F23")
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
Range("A24:F33").Select
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet4").Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet4").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A25:A33") _
    , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet4").Sort
    .SetRange Range("A24:F33")
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
```

End Sub

Comment: Why not add a column that says which category each row is in, and sort by that field first, *then* date? VBA isn't necessary.

Comment: That's what I basically did, I added the Row F and created the categories to sort the data @rdhs. It's just that I don't want to keep manually selecting the data since it changes a lot when it can be automated

Comment: What I'm suggesting though is that you just select the entire columns A:F. In the sort dialog, sort by column F first, and then add a level to sort by column A. You should only have to do one sort on the entire range of data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider changing your order of operations. I would recommend sorting all of your data by date first (column A) then sort by your other criteria (Column F). Doing so should order your data by date within each L, RI, R.

Should not require a VBA code to accomplish what I am describing when using the filter tool under the "Data" ribbon.

In case you just really want to automate this:

```
Rows("1:1").Select 'Column Headers Row
Selection.AutoFilter
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range _
    ("A1"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
    xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").AutoFilter.Sort
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range _
    ("F1"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
    xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").AutoFilter.Sort
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
```

End Sub